# hg-git push complaining about public key

Tags: git, mercurial

I've been using [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.io/) fine up until this point, pushing and pulling from my git repo with mercurial. Today all of a sudden I get the following error:

```
❯ hg push
pushing to git+ssh://git@github.com/User/myrepo.git
Permission denied (publickey).
abort: git remote error: The remote server unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

After this, I double checked my public keys were still in fact there and associated with my git account. Nothing has changed since my last push other than my restarting my computer. Anyone have any idea what could be the problem? The error message isn't the most helpful.

My .hgrc is just the usual:

```
[ui]
username = My Name <myname@domain.com>

[extensions]
hgext.convert=
hgext.bookmarks =
hggit =
```

Comment: Can you please try to ssh into `git@github.com` and confirm it works?  You should get a message like "Hi, [username]!  You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."

Comment: Oh shoot nope I get a Permission denied (publickey). Looks like that could actually be the problem. Hmmm

Comment: Sounds like either your local SSH environment has changed (did you regenerate your SSH keys, perhaps?) or you removed your public key from Github via their settings page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must to provide your **public key** to GitHub (SSH-agent or PageAnt depending from OS)

Comment: https://github.com/settings/ssh/new if you were looking for it... so nice of GitHub to let me push for 15 minutes before rejecting me :'(